# How to read an xaml file and get the data I want in C#

Tags: c#, xaml

I want to read through a xaml file, and find all the lines with 'Annotation.AnnotationText' and get specific data from that line.For example, this line:

```
 <prwab:Branch Condition="{x:Null}" sap2010:Annotation.AnnotationText="testing information " ContinuouslyExecute="False" CreatedBy="System Administrator" CreatedOn="2013-02-23T14:51:28.1555955-05:00" DisplayName="Failure" EnableValidationRule="False" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="160,234" ID="ab91dec8-1976-491e-91eb-58e073a69d16" IsReportable="False" LastModifiedBy="System Administrator" LastModifiedOn="2013-02-23T14:51:28.1555955-05:00" MediaRecord="[MediaRecord]" SystemName="CollectDigitsActivity1 Failure6" Timeout="10000" Type="Voice">
```

I want find all the lines with 'AnnotationText' in my xaml file, and get information like text = 'testing information', id = 'ab91dec8-1976-491e-91eb-58e073a69d16' , created date and lastmodified date.

I have 0 knowledge in this area and I don't know where to start and which method should I use. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

XAML is just a specific flavour of XML. You will need to use XML parsing to read the file into an object that you can process in this manner. I recommend Linq to XML for this (look at XDocument class to get started), specifically as finding values by XName using a specific namespace as you will need to for the "sap2010" namespace is very easy.

You can then easily parse and extract the information you are looking for using those classes.